# How to create a dialog with editText Android

Tags: android

When the button "AddNewTask", a dialog will pop up like this:

**Task Name:**

|____________|

Cancel || Submit

And then, i want to put that value in an array of Strings.

**For example:**

Array taskSubmitted = { task1, task2 }; //if the user submitted 2 tasks

and also print all the values from Array taskSubmitted.

How to do that? I'm a beginner in Android. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: >__< pretty pleaseeeeee...... i need it. I don't understand with the notes. That problem i posted is just the basic simple , i have to customize it futher (if ever u gave me codes) to suit my project.

Comment: its simple ruby not that much hard..simply use Custum dialog box

Comment: A very complicated app. If you look at my profile, i have asked some several question from past 2 days. Look at those questions i wrote before.

Comment: @Ruby What you asked in this question isn't complicated. But looking at your question history, it seems like you need to learn how to write a good question. You'll get a much better response out of people. Look at this next time: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What about googling for `android custom dialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

final EditText edittext = new EditText(ActivityContext);
alert.setMessage("Enter Your Message");
alert.setTitle("Enter Your Title");

alert.setView(edittext);

alert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
        //What ever you want to do with the value
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // what ever you want to do with No option.
    }
});

alert.create().show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   public void method()
   {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    EditText    et= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    }
```

you have to just call the above method anywhere 
in activity and fetch edittext.